# Unity child game objects not becoming active when parent.SetActive(true);?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, communityengine

I have a very unique bug when I dynamically switch between menus by setting them to active/inactive with .SetActive(). The bug is that one and only one of the menus is not recursively setting its children even though the parent object is set to active. I've read that child objects won't be affected by the parent SetActive if they are unchecked in the inspector, but I can check every single object as active and it still happens. I guess my question then is, is there something I can do in the editor to reset the objects so that they work again?

I'm not going to provide any of my code because this must be an issue with the editor. My objects are handled dynamically, and it is only one of the menus that is misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a new game object to replace the parent, and moved all the children to it. Now it works fine! I have no idea what would cause that. Maybe a bug.